# Docker build and security updates, best practices?

Tags: docker

I'm currently moving an app that was installed directly on a server to a docker image. To that matter, I've created a Dockerfile that `apt-get install` my packages and then install my app inside the image.

My question is the following:

How should I handle security updates? I'm installing several packages in that image but, by default, `docker build` reuses the previous layers.

I see 3 possibilities:

- Build using `--no-cache` (or just `--pull`?)
- Add an `unattended-upgrade` at the end of the Dockerfile
- Security updates, who cares? (not my favorite solution... But is it the common practice since it's the default behavior?)

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I usually put an apt-get upgrade at the beginning of the Dockerfile. And once per month I issue a `--no-cache` build. Also I issue a `docker pull` of the image my container is derived from. For example `docker pull ubuntu:xenial`

If you use Jenkins it is easy to put a job once per month to do the above.

The `unattended-upgrade` option looks interesting. Let's see if an answer includes it as an option.

Regards